# Yocto is not booting up

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, yocto

I get a new kernel(3.14) from kontron for my board after i compiled and try to run it on my board but i getting the following error any one can help me !

**Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)**

Answer (score 0):

The kernel can't find its root filesystem.

Investigate why that is the case. Where is the kernel looking for it? Check the kernel config and/or the command line passed from the bootloader. Check that the kernel has all the drivers to actually access the hardware hosting the root filesystem. Has the kernel the needed filesystem support complied in?